# Input field number format AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input field:

```
<input type="text" class="span2" ng-model="mynumber">
```

mynumber has the value 0.55 which is loaded on pageload from a rest service. My problem is now, how can I format the number for different languages/countries? For example, in German, the value should be formatted with a comma (`,`) instead of a period (`.`). And if the user changes the number the number should be converted to `.` instead of `,`, if I send it back to the rest service.

This should also work for larger numbers like `90,000.00`, which should be `90.000,00` in German...

If I use the `angular-locale_de-at.js`, I can format the number on a normal output with this:

```
{{mynumber | number}}
```

but that does not work for an input field.

How can I handle this? The values should be (printed) formatted in the input field.

If I canage the type of the input field to number

```
<input type="number" class="span2" ng-model="mynumber">
```

it works in chrome but not in IE or FF. in chrome i get 0,55. but not in other browsers.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've written the directive you are looking for. See [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/ST-Software/STAngular/blob/master/src/directives/SgNumberInput).

Also see this answer on SO
[Using AngularJS directive to format input field while leaving scope variable unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094150/using-angularjs-directive-to-format-input-field-while-leaving-scope-variable-unc)

It will probably not work with `<input type="number"/>`, use `<input type="text"/>` instead

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text in your question.  External links are no substitute for code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Mh,

my first idea would be to separate the concerns here. You're having the model `mynumber` on the one side and the representation on the other side. Those are distinct from my point of view.

So what you can do is to introduce a directive (I once did this for date values in AngularJS 1.1.5, so bit a bit of additional hacking could be necessary):

First we introduce a directive:

```
<input type="text" class="span2" ng-model="mynumber" number-format>
```

with the code:

```
var app = angular.module("your.directives", ['your.filters']);
app.directive("numberFormat", [
  '$filter', function(filter) {
    return {
      replace: false,
      restrict: "A",
      require: "?ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var numberFormat;
        if (!ngModel) {
          return;
        }
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          return element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
        var numberFilter = filter('myNumberFilter');
        return ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
          return numberFilter(value);
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

What you need for this, is a working `myNumberFilter` filter present, which could decide based on the language given (however you determine this) how to format the input value.

EDIT: I noticed, that AngularJS has it's own number filter, so i changed the name called. Let's add our own:

```
var app = angular.module("your.filters", []);

app.filter("myNumberFilter", ['SiteLanguage', 
  function(siteLanguage) {
    return function(number) {
      var language = siteLanguage.getLanguage(); //I assume you have a service that can tell you the current language
      switch(language) {
          case "de":
          // return the variant of number for "de" here
          break;
          case "fr":
          // return the variant of number for "fr" here
          break;
          default:
          // return english variant here.
          break;
        };
    }
  ]
});
```

You'll probably need a formatter function for the individual countries (instead of blindly relying on `angular locale`. And you probably need a service `SiteLanguage` which will give you the language on the current site.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: first of all, thank you, basically it works... there is a small bug ... i have to use `var numberFilter = filter('number');` instead of `var numberFilter = filter('numberFilter');` ... the problem is, if i show the values in german and i click on save (send it to the rest service), the german format is used ... but it should be english ... any idea? the value should stay in english because of the DB. it's only a display issue.

Comment: ah yeah `numberFilter`may be a bad name, as you have to write your own and angular has it's own filter called that way. Let me do a quick edit. How do you determine the language on the site?

Comment: and if i send the value back to the rest service ... how can i deal with this problem? how can i set all values back to english? i send a json object with all values from the page to a rest service ...

Comment: phew, that is a more complex problem and a whole bunch of separate questions - could you provider a fiddle or a plunkr with a sample setup?

Comment: with `$http({method: 'GET', url:` ... i get a JSON object which i display and which can be edited by the user ... if the user saves the values i make a `$http({method: 'PUT', url:` ... that's all ... no big deal ... the problem is only the languagespecific display... and converting to the english format if the user stores the values

Comment: As i said, please make a a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net or a plunkr at http://plunker.co - i cannot infer your whole setup :)