# $parsers and $formatters are being called only once, instead of on every value update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to create a directive named `currency` that appends a `$` before the text in input. The dollar sign should be shown at all times and shouldn't be possible to remove.

Here's my code:

```
app.directive('currency', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {

      // view -> model
      controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
        viewValue = viewValue.replace(/^\$/, '');
        controller.$viewValue = viewValue;
        return viewValue;
      });

      // model -> view
      controller.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
        modelValue = '$' + modelValue;
        controller.$modelValue = modelValue;
        return modelValue;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29012/

As you can see, the dollar sign is appended initially, but can be deleted and won't be appended after that. It seems that the function I push to `$formatters` is only being called once. Is it supposed to work like that or am I missing something? How can I implement the desired behavior?

Comment: possible same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094150/using-angularjs-directive-to-format-input-field-while-leaving-scope-variable-unc

Comment: If you type in the input field you're triggering the $parsers and not the $formatters. You can test this by adding a second input field that manipulates the same ngModel. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29013/

Comment: Formatters will NOT be called when the model is changed in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i have tried a workaround, it works but i am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29014/

```
controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
      //console.log(viewValue.substring(0,1));

      if(viewValue.substring(0,1) != "$"){
            var view_value = "$" + viewValue;
          controller.$setViewValue(view_value);
          controller.$render();
      }
        viewValue = viewValue.replace(/^\$/, '');
        //controller.$viewValue = viewValue;


        console.log(viewValue);
        return viewValue;
      });
```

P.S: i am not sure why you are injecting `ngModel` as `controller` in your `link` function. it might be a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not quite understanding what the $parsers and $formatters do. Whenever you enter something in the input field, the $parsers are responsible for converting this value into a model value. Formatters are responsible for converting a model value into a display value in your input field.

What you are attempting to do is to change the content of your input field ($formatter feature) when someone enters something into the field ($parser feature).

While I'm sure there are workarounds to making it work this way, you're misusing the concepts of $parsers and $formatters when you do. Instead you should be looking at a custom directive (or extend the one you have) to add to the input that does what you're trying to do, for instance by handing keyups.

**Edit**

See the following code example for a link function to give you some indication of what I mean:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {

  elem.bind('keyup', function(evt) {
     // Change the displayed value after every keypress
     // This function is an example and needs serious work...
     // Perhaps you should even put this in a separate directive
     var value = elem.val().replace(/[^$0-9]/g, '');
     if (value && value.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
        value = '$' + value;
     }
     elem.val(value);
  });

  // view -> model
  controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
    // Any time the view changes, remove the $ sign and interpret the rest as number for the model
    var modelValue = viewValue.replace(/^\$/, '');
    return parseFloat(modelValue);
  });

  // model -> view
  controller.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
    // Any time the model (number) changes, append it with a $ sign for the view
    var viewValue = '$' + modelValue;
    return viewValue;
  });
}
```

Or check the entire fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cL0hpvp4/

Comment: Care to show an example? If I append `$` to the input value, it will be stored in the model, right? I don't want that, only the displayed value needs to change.