# AngularJS format number field with thousands separator

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using AngularJS, I have a number field `<input type="number" ng-model="requisite.values.cost">`. Is it possible to automatically format this field, separating the thousands with a space?

Meaning, so that when the value `requisite.values.cost` is `1000000`, it will display in the number field `1 000 000`, for easier readability.

Comment: Example of input field formatting:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094150/using-angularjs-directive-to-format-input-field-while-leaving-scope-variable-unc

Comment: Thank you for your link Zaxxon, though it's regarding a text field, as in `input type="text"`, as opposed to `input type="number"`. Would it be the same with a `number` field?

Comment: I think you'd have to do it in a text field to get custom formatting.  Of course, you'd have to handle the conversion into a number for use in your back end.